# 他の人の投稿を編集したら、投稿者にはどのように通知されるのでしょうか

Tags: サポート, 編集

Stack Overflowに来たばかりで自分の投稿を編集されることに慣れていない方にとって、編集されることがどんな印象になるのかを把握したいと考えています。

おそらくトップバーの受信箱に赤い数字が表示されるのだと思いますが、

1. 受信箱を開いた時にどういう内容が表示されるか

   - とくに、編集サマリーは表示されるのか
2. その通知をクリックした時にどういう画面に遷移するか

が知りたいです。文章での回答でも、スクリーンショットでもOKです。

Comment: 試しに編集してみましたが通知確認出来ないですかね？

Comment: @tomute 通知がまだ来ていないです。探したところ、[meta.se](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239145/157841)で、ある程度の量の変更がないと通知が来ない・量があっても通知が来ないことがある(?)という投稿を見つけました。[サンドボックス](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/a/1656/30)にテスト用の回答を追加したので、ごっそり書き換えるような編集をおねがいできますか?

Comment: 大幅な編集やってみました。

Comment: @tomute ありがとうございます。通知の内容を確認できました。

Comment: 上手くいって良かったです。

Answer (score 3):

自分の投稿が編集されると、受信箱に通知が届きます:

[image: トップバー]

↓ クリックすると、編集された投稿へのリンクが出てきます。

[image: 受信箱]

↓ リンク先はその投稿の編集履歴画面です。

[image: 編集履歴]